# Connecting to DB using JDBC driver with different user login

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

I have opened sql with other user (Shift+Right click and run as different user) by providing user name and password, hence when I connect to SQL Server, with windows authentication am able to access the DB's and tables.

Now, can I do this using Java? When I use below code:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName;Database=Testing;integratedSecurity=true");
```

Error:
Login failed for user so and so. This is actually correct because it is taking the login information of system I am currently using.

Comment: Please provide the full exception stack trace. And did you start the Java process with the user you want to use for Windows Authentication, because that is the important factor here: the user running the process.

Comment: Thanks Mark for revert , when you say "did you start java process" what exactly is this ? am running automation code in eclipse and trying to connect to DB using java API , am logging with credentials A , but i want to connect to sql with Credentials B (WIndows Authentication)through Java code

Comment: Add information to your question by editing, don't use comments to post more information and things like stacktraces. As to your second comment: the default way of windows authentication takes the user information from the process running the Java process. So if you started it as user A, you can only authenticate as user A. You can't switch a process user, and I'm not sure if there is another mechanism that would allow for that.

Comment: Ok .. understood ! Thanks again

Comment: So there is no chance of doing this ?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : This is what developers using for connection Server = Abc; Database = dbTest; User Id = domainName\\user1; Password = pwd; Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info= true;Trusted_Connection=True; in Visual studi , but when i try with above credentials with JDBC connection , am not able to connect to SQL , can you help me solving this with above query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to [JDBC connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017#connection-examples) your new password and username

> jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****;

So in your code:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName;Database=Testing;integratedSecurity=true;user=MyUserName;password=*****");
```

> Note
>
> Although the previous example uses a username and password in the connection string, you should use integrated security as it is more secure. For more information, see the [Connecting with Integrated Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017#Connectingintegrated) section later in this topic.